# To check if a mentioned user has the role or not in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a administration bot in discord with discord.js. I am trying to make a command which gives the user a specific role. So I want to make it check first if that user has that specific role beforehand or not to avoid errors. The problem lies in the if statement which checks if the user has the role, its giving me a error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')". Please suggest me how to fix this.

```
const {
    Role,
    ThreadManager
} = require("discord.js");
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports = {
    name: 'gulag',
    description: "gulag",
    execute(message, args) {

        if (message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATORS")) {
            const target = message.mentions.users.first();
            const check = message.mentions.users.first();
            if (target) {

                let gulagRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'gulag');
                let memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);


                if (check.roles.has(gulagRole.id)) {
                    message.reply(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}> is already in gulag.`)
                } else {
                    memberTarget.roles.add(gulagRole.id);
                    message.channel.send(`<@${memberTarget.user.id}>`);
                    message.channel.send('https://tenor.com/view/gulag-warzone-call-of-duty-cod-battle-royale-gif-16853559');
                }


            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using **Discord.js v13**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go straight for `message.mentions.members.first()` because this will return `GuildMember` so it is easier to then check the roles

```js
const target = message.mentions.members.first()
if(target){
      if(target.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'gulag')){
            //REST OF THE STUFF
      }
}
```

If you are using **v13** remember to declare Intents for your Client as well.

Comment: Okay thanks it works!

Comment: Great @Bolt remember to mark it as solved, (checkmark on the answer)